# Questioning Apple's new 3D Touch

Tags: usability, user-behavior

I have serious doubts that Apple's 3D Touch will be a huge "success" with users unless there is a hint that touchable components in fact do support it. 
I am not a UX expert, so the points that I'll bring up are merely based on the little knowledge I have acquired as a design enthusiast and UX aficionado.

**1) Recognition rather than recall**

In UX this has become a rule that UX experts abide by religiously, so why should it be different with Apple's 3D Touch ? Why/How should users recall that an icon supports 3D Touch ? More importantly, how should they recall which actions are supported by the opening menu? The more intuitive way is to tap an image to enlarge it, right ?

The counter argument is the case of context menus on desktops we know and love (right click components to show actions) such as copy & pasting text. The thing is, that those context menus often do have a predefined set of actions that are universally known (and **recalled**) by users (e.g. Copy, Paste, Settings), which will probably not be as consistent in iOS apps.

**Suggestion towards recognition:**

Instead of guessing whether a visual component supports 3D Touch:

[image: Source: http://www.apple.com/iphone-6s/3d-touch/]

**Steer towards recognition -> Add a visual guide that the component supports it:** *(The hint icon looks terrible, I know, this is just a quick draw-up for illustrating my point)*

[image]

Of course this wouldn't make much sense in the case illustrated (as all app icons support 3D Touch by default), but in general (custom built apps that support 3D Touch in their interface).

**2) Significant delay in interaction -> hampering UX**

From what could be seen in the demos, enlarging an image takes 50ms (?) or more, why would you even bother to hold down to enlarge an image when you can just enlarge it with a tap, which is probably much faster anyway ?

I am looking forward to hearing what experts (or more experienced people) on here think about this.

Comment: While I like the question, this will lead to primarily discussion and opinion based answers which isn't allowed in this Q&A format. Could you try rewording this into a more "answerable" question rather than just looking for input from the experts?

Comment: @DasBeasto That's a shame, I was looking to gather as much information in a discussion-like format. I'll try to think about ways to rephrase my question...

Comment: yeah I see @DasBeasto point, it's hard to have an evidence-based conversation about a new feature though. I guess there are comparisons to be made between 3D touch and long press...so maybe there are some long press gesture research pieces etc. I guess apple's assumption is that all apps will start to use the feature on their icon e.g. put their primary task and their settings link in menu that appears. In the case of twitter 'tweet, settings'. Maybe the question should be 'is 3D touch just glorified long-press or right-click?' :) I think the thread you've start definitely warrants discussion

Comment: FYI, this would be a great topic for Chat.

Comment: @DA01Where can I find the chat ? Edit: Okay, think I found it. How would I go about asking this ? Should I link this question ?

Comment: I like this question. Perhaps it could be rephrased in the form of "does 3d touch comport with solid UX design principles?"